# Mac Terminal error '-bash: ./js: Permission denied'

Tags: command-line, javascriptmvc

I'm learning JavascriptMVC and I'm running the following command in the Terminal, which I got from [here](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/getstarted.html#&who=creating):

```
./js jquery/generate/app cookbook
```

I'm new to the command line. All of my Googling is coming up with nothing. I imagine I'm missing some kind of configuration or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error likely means that 'js' isn't executable. If it's in the current directory, you can make it executable with `chmod +x js`.